# Select...in (column1) where column1 is '1,4,7'

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I need to perform a 'where in(X)' search in which the value of X is a comma separated list of values from a table.

Table-1:

```
itemId   colors(nvarchar)
 1          1, 3
 2          2
```

Table-2:

```
colorId colorName
   1      Red
   2      Yellow
   3      Blue
```

I'm looking for this sort of output...

```
itemId colorName
  1     Red
  1     Blue
```

I tried this but I think the inner Select needs to return multiple rows for this to work correctly, not a single row whose value is a comma separated value.

```
select itemId, colorName 
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t2.colorId in (select colors from Table1 where itemId = 1)
where itemId = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be you can use find_in_set

```
select itemId, colorName 
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on  find_in_set(t2.colorId , t1.colors) > 0
where itemId = 1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 0):

In the name of normalization you should really turn table1 into

```
itemid | colorid
-------+--------
     1 |       1
     1 |       3
     2 |       2
```

not only are those comma-separated fields annoying to update, but find_in_set is one of those functions that I would avoid if ever possible. (because effectively you're searching for a number in a string, that usually means searching a string, which is less efficient than just using the table as proposed and adding useful indices)

anyway, if you'd change table_1 the query would be:

```
SELECT t1.itemid, t2.colorname
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 USING (colorid)
WHERE t1.itemid=1
ORDER BY t1.itemid
```

if by any chance you need a list of color names:

```
SELECT t1.itemid, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.colorname)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 USING (colorid)
WHERE ...
GROUP BY t1.itemid
```

which would return the tuples (1,"Red,Blue") and (2,"Yellow").

(and similarly with `GROUP_CONCAT(t2.colorid)`)

Comment: Understood, not my schema as the saying goes.  And this is a rarely non-performant bit of SQL so I have bigger fish to fry than tackle this annoying bit of schema.